# MS-Word, how can I use a base template to be derived by my on-going templates?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, word-template, word-2016

I am using several different Word templates, mainly because of different layouts and structure. I want them all to use a "base-template" that has my several styles. And of course, if I add or update a style - I want **all the templates to be updated**.
Is there a way for doing this? 
I'm using Word (2013 / 2016)

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to directly "inherit" from a template. The best you can do is create a so-called "Style Set" (Word 2013 and newer), save it to a file and place it into the `AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Quick Styles` folder of your user profile.

Check this tutorial to see how to create a custom style set: [How to create and share custom Style Sets](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2156364/how-to-create-and-share-custom-style-sets.html) and this blog post that explains the difference to themes: [Changing your style in the new Word](https://blogs.office.com/2012/09/06/changing-your-style-in-the-new-word/).

However, you can't use it to automatically update existing documents or templates. A style set only is applied to a template or document, i.e. you basically create a copy of everything (and not a reference to the style set). This is to make sure that the document is self-contained and can be shared with people who don't have the style set.

Comment: I've noticed that when I'm creating a new style set - it is saved as a *.dotx (the template format) - so I'm rigtht back to square one because I need one "style set" to affect several templates. Am I missing something in your answer?